# FASM Bootloader input

Tags: assembly, input, bootloader, fasm

I started on making a bootloader from scratch in FASM. I just made a basic input.
But I don't know how to do something.

This is my code:

```
start:
mov ax, 07C0h 
add ax, 288     
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, 4096 
mov ax, 07C0h 
mov ds, ax 
mov si, text_string 
call print_string
jmp read  ; infinite loop of reading!
text_string db '<HammerOS> : Booted up!', 13, 10, 0

read:
mov ah,0h   ;get character from keyboard
int 16h     ;and store it in AL
mov ah,0eh  ;Display a character in AL
int 10h     ;aka, echo it

jmp read

have_read_txt:
mov si, AL
call print_string

print_string:     
mov ah, 0Eh 

.repeat: 
lodsb     
cmp al, 0 
je .done 
int 10h  
jmp .repeat 

.done: 
ret 


times 510-($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xAA55
```

What it does it it accepts input on console, but when I press enter I want to check the content of the input and based on that I want to do stuff.

Also, I want the cursor to go to the next line. Now if I press enter the text will write over the same line.

Answer (score 1):

In place where you get the char and then write it on screen you will also need to store the char in some memory buffer.

When you detect 'enter' key by comparing AL with 'enter' key code, which should be 13 or 10, you need to analyze your buffer and do stuff.
List of 
[ascii codes here](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/); may be usefull.

If you want to move your cursor, take a look at int 10h (which you already use) description:
[BIOS interrupt call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call).

Comment: How do I make a memory buffer? Is it with db or with a memory segment?

Comment: Yes, your text string is also a memory buffer. But it is a mistake for trying to move a value from an 8 bit register(AL) to a 16 bit register(SI) with the "mov" instruction. Use "movzx" or the 16 bit AX register instead.

Comment: I try moving it to a buffer but then it will endessly print the input char. I use:         mov [buffer], al

Comment: @JoshuaBakker: I think you should start with some assembler tutorials before you start writing OS. You miss the very basic knowledge

Comment: I tried searching for buffers in ASM but couldn't find anything. Is there a difference in difficultly between FASM, NASM, MASM and EMU8086?

Comment: the easiest way, when you write an os, is just to say that at point X in memory I'll have a buffer. You simply need to be sure nothing important is there. In your case, you can use for example 0x7c00 + 512 (just after your code). Or define a table in your program, so it will be residing along with code. Take a look at http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#1.2.2 to see how to do that (see `dup` operator - you can use it to fill some area with zeros)

Comment: NASM_Doc: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html "zerobuf: times 64 db 0" ... resb, resw, ....